# VBA code to extract Substring from Main String

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to extract substring from main string. String have not same pattern. Main string is in Column "I". Desired output should be as per column "J". I have to extract substring between "FL" and "WNG".

[image: Data of string]

I have tried to write code put it is not giving proper output. Can you please assist with alternate solution to get desired output using VBA.

```
Sub Get_Substring()
    
Range("K2") = Mid(Range("I2"), InStrRev(Range("I2"), "FL") + 1, _
                                        InStrRev(Range("I2"), "WNG") - _
                                        InStrRev(Range("I2"), "FL") - 1)
End Sub
```

Comment: Another way? `Debug.Print Split(Split(MyString, "REGNO")(1), "FL")(0)` and `Debug.Print "L" & Split(Split(Split(MyString, "REGNO")(1), "WNG")(0), "FL")(1)` will give you `02` and `L02` respectively.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll chuck in a solution based on regex to assure you got the exact substring:

```
Sub Test()

Dim stringIn As String: stringIn = "John12REGNO02FL02WNGARM01"
Debug.Print (Extract(stringIn))

End Sub

Function Extract(stringIn As String) As String

With CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
    .Pattern = "^.*FL(.*?)WNG"
    If .Test(stringIn) = True Then
        Extract = .Execute(stringIn)(0).Submatches(0)
    Else
        Extract = "None Found"
    End If
End With

End Function
```

- `^` - Start line anchor.
- `.*FL` - 0+ Chars greedy, and therefor untill, the last occurence of "FL".
- `(.*?)` - A capture group with 0+ but lazy characters and therefor upto the nearest occurence of:
- `WNG` - Literally match "WNG".

NOTE, you could make a more strict pattern only catching digits of that's the only type of characters possible, e.g: `^.*FL(\d*)WNG`.

Here is an online [demo](https://regex101.com/r/JmbQQC/1)

Answer (score 4):

Try the following...

```
Range("K2") = Mid(Range("I2"), InStrRev(Range("I2"), "FL") + 2, _
                                        InStrRev(Range("I2"), "WNG") - _
                                        InStrRev(Range("I2"), "FL") - 2)
```

Although, I would make it clear that you want the value for each of the ranges, as follows...

```
Range("K2").Value = Mid(Range("I2").Value, InStrRev(Range("I2").Value, "FL") + 2, _
                                        InStrRev(Range("I2").Value, "WNG") - _
                                        InStrRev(Range("I2").Value, "FL") - 2)
```

Answer (score 3):

The next piece of code extracts the necessary string using arrays, too. But it can do it, even if more "WNG" strings exist in the string to be analyzed:

```
Private Function ExtractString(strTxt As String) As String
  Dim arrFL, arrWNG, i As Long

  arrFL = Split(strTxt, "FL")
  For i = 1 To UBound(arrFL)               'start from the second array element
        arrWNG = Split(arrFL(i), "WNG")   'split each first array element by "WNG"
        'if the array contains at least a "WNG" string:
        If UBound(arrWNG) > 0 Then ExtractString = arrWNG(0): Exit Function 'extract the first array element
  Next
End Function
```

Note: If more pairs "FL" folowed by "WNG" exists, the function can be adapted to return an array, containing all such potential occurrences...

It can be tested using the next testing `Sub`:

```
Sub testExtractString()
  Dim x As String
    x = "John12REGNO02FL02WNGARM01"
    'x = "John12WNGREGNO02FL02WNGARM01"
    'x = "John12WNGREGNO02FL02WNGARWNGM01"
   Debug.Print ExtractString(x)
End Sub
```

Just uncomment each x definition row...

Comment: Straight forward +)

Answer (score 2):

You can try the following udf:

```
Public Function FLWNG(s As String) As String
'Purpose: get the substring enclosed by the most right pair of FL..WNG
    Dim tmp
    tmp = Split(Replace(s, "WNG", "FL"), "FL")
    FLWNG = tmp(UBound(tmp) - 1)
End Function
```

**Explanation**

*Replacing* all occurencies of `WNG` in the original string (`s`) with `FL` allows to *split* the resulting string by the `FL` delimiter only.

Assuming that the original string has at least one enclosing structure, you get the enclosed content as next to last element, i.e. via `tmp(Ubound(tmp)-1)`.

Comment: Nice, as usually, voted it up. It splits perfectly the strings we can see. Hypothetically, if there are more "WNG" strings, it should be necessary to choose the next such string coming after "FL". I think, making a second array split by "WNG" and extract the first its element will better make the trick... I will try making such a function, even if it can be more complicated than the classical version using `Mid` and `InStr`, just for the sake of playing with arrays...:)